# Creating two columns from consecutive dates of a column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this.

```
row_number   date          
----------   ----
1           2018-01-15
2           2018-01-27
3           2018-03-20
4           2019-01-30
```

My aim is to make like the following.

```
beginning_date     ending_date
--------------     -----------
 2018-01-15        2018-01-27
 2018-01-27        2018-03-20
 2018-03-20        2019-01-30
```

What kind of a query is needed for making this in T-Sql?
How can I also bring info of the 4th row (table has other columns) into the new beginning and ending date table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.row_number, t.date, lead(date) over (order by t.row_number) as ending_date
      from table t
     ) t
where ending_date is not null;
```

**EDIT :** If you want all rows then remove filter :

```
select t.row_number, t.date, lead(date) over (order by t.row_number) as ending_date
from table t;
```

If you want same date as beginning date that has no end date then you can do :

```
lead(date, 1, date) over (order by t.row_number) as ending_date
```

Comment: How can I also bring info of the 4th row (table has other columns) into the new beginning and ending date table?

Comment: @sebnears. . . Then use only `subquery` or remove filter `ending_date is not null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select date as beginning_date, ending_date
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as ending_date
      from t
     ) t
where ending_date is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option (same logic, different format):

```sql
SELECT beginning_date, ending_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    MAX(date) OVER(
      ORDER BY row_number ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS beginning_date,
    date AS ending_date
  FROM mytable
) src
WHERE beginning_date IS NOT NULL -- Ignore first row
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12de4/10)

Comment: Why would you want to do this rather than the much clearer `LEAD`?

Comment: You are right, `LEAD` is much cleaner.  But the user does not specify what version of SQL Server he's on.  It looks like `LEAD` wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2012.

Comment: that was also when support for your answer was introduced. Before that windowed aggregates didn't support the order by clause.

Comment: Heh...well in that case, ya got me :)

Comment: No prob bob. :)